# Cоздание копии файла

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

Как сделать запись в файл создав копию файла **1.exe (как на примере)**  ?

В коде что предоставлен ниже: Идет Запись текста из **Memo1** в файл **1.exe**, перезаписывая его. А нужно чтобы создавалась копия файла  **Copy_1.exe.**

```
var
  aStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
// Запись с memo в файл (используя компонент idencoderxxe1)
Memo1.Text:=idencoderxxe1.EncodeString(Memo1.text);

aStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
Memo1.Lines.SaveToStream(aStream);
AttachToFile(1.exe, aStream); // Вот тут идет прямая запись, а нужно что бы создавался второй файл Copy_1.exe

// Освобождаем
aStream.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1109423/365777) на другой ваш вопрос это уже было решено.

Требуется всего лишь предварительно скопировать файл `1.exe` в `Copy_1.exe`.

Полный текст:

```
var
  aStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  TFile.Copy('1.exe', 'Copy_1.exe');

// Запись с memo в файл (используя компонент idencoderxxe1)
  Memo1.Text:=idencoderxxe1.EncodeString(Memo1.text);

  aStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Memo1.Lines.SaveToStream(aStream);
  AttachToFile('Copy_1.exe', aStream); // запись в Copy_1.exe

// Освобождаем
  aStream.Free;
end;
```

Если требуется компиляция под *Delphi7*, то можно использовать `CopyFile` из *WinApi*.

Comment: Именно то что нужно! Спасибо все заработало именно как нужно!